# why docker-compose set systemd-coredump as user when mouting mysql volume?

Tags: docker-compose

I need to add conf file to my mysql volume to create a volume logs but I do not have the permissions on my host machine.

When I run docker-compose the "mysql" folder is created with the followed permissions:

```sh
$ ls -l mysql/
total 198068
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump       56 févr.  2 21:36  auto.cnf
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  3117703 févr.  2 21:36  binlog.000001
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      157 févr.  2 21:36  binlog.000002
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump       32 févr.  2 21:36  binlog.index
-rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1680 févr.  2 21:36  ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1112 févr.  2 21:36  ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1112 févr.  2 21:36  client-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1680 févr.  2 21:36  client-key.pem
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump   196608 févr.  2 21:36 '#ib_16384_0.dblwr'
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  8585216 févr.  2 21:36 '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     5714 févr.  2 21:36  ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 12582912 févr.  2 21:36  ibdata1
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 50331648 févr.  2 21:36  ib_logfile0
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 50331648 févr.  2 21:36  ib_logfile1
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 12582912 févr.  2 21:36  ibtmp1
drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 févr.  2 21:36 '#innodb_temp'
drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 févr.  2 21:36  mysql
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 31457280 févr.  2 21:36  mysql.ibd
drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 févr.  2 21:36  performance_schema
-rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1680 févr.  2 21:36  private_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      452 févr.  2 21:36  public_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1112 févr.  2 21:36  server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1680 févr.  2 21:36  server-key.pem
drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 févr.  2 21:36  symfony_docker
drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 févr.  2 21:36  sys
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 16777216 févr.  2 21:36  undo_001
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 16777216 févr.  2 21:36  undo_002
```

Why it does not mount my volume with my user like my others volumes ?

```sh
  database:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "${MYSQL_LOCAL_PORT}:${MYSQL_DOCKER_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - my-admin-sys
```

I did try to add user with GID and UID but it did not fixed the issue.

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer may come too late, I would like to write what I did in the same situation. Maybe it can help others.

Create a file `Dockerfile.mysql` and add the following lines in it:

```
FROM mysql:8.0

# Set the user and group to match my local user and group.
RUN usermod -u $(id -u) mysql
RUN groupmod -g $(id -g) mysql
```

Modify your `docker-compose.yml` in the following way:
Replace the line

```
    image: mysql:8.0
```

by the following lines:

```
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.mysql
```

If you now run `docker-compose up`, a new image is created and run for you which has the required user and group ownership.